# Finding the Matrix Representation of a Linear Transformation with the Domain being a Derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, linear-transformations

For a set of transformations, I have to find their matrix representations using the Standard Basis of their Domains.

I'm stuck on the following set:

$D :  P^3 \to P^2 $, $D$ is the first derivative

$D :  P^3 \to P^3 $, $D$ is the first derivative

$T :  P^4 \to P^2 $, $T$ is the second derivative

How would I go about finding a matrix representation for this sort of problem? I know what a derivative is, but I'm unsure of what the definitions here even mean. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been searching online and through my textbook for a couple of hours now...

Comment: Define notation please. Example, what $V$ is and what do you mean by "standard basis" $S.$

Comment: I edited it. V is Domain from the notation T:V->W (Transformation:Domain->Range). By standard basis I mean the orthonormal basis vectors that the set can span from.

Comment: You are losing me. If there is an orthogonal generating set, what is the inner product? What is $P^k$ for $k = 2, 3, 4$? I mean, maybe is obvious to you but I can't think what these things mean. Please rewrite the question so that anyone can understand what the notation mean.

Comment: It's not obvious to me, and now you're losing me :p. Standard basis as defined here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardBasis.html.

Comment: So, $P^3$ is $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: @WillM. $P^3$ is defined here as $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4)$, or all polynomials with a maximum degree of $3$ with real coefficients.

Comment: I was imagining that $P^3$ was for polynomials whose degree was at most three. I was intended that OP would clarify and learn to exaplain what his notation meant. By the wat, since he is talking about derivative, I think that $P^3$ is the space of polynomial _functions_ (hence, a subspace of the product space $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R},$ not of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},$ hence, even less of $\Bbb R[x]/(x^4).$).

Comment: @WillM. to be fair, you don't need to consider polynomials as functions to define a formal derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$D:P^3\to P^2$ acts as $(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) \to (3ax^2+2bx+c)$ .

In vector form with standard basis :

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\d
\end{bmatrix} \to
\begin{bmatrix}
3a\\2b\\c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the matrix that represents this transformation is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&0\\
0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I think that you can do from this for the other cases.

Comment: Thanks! I see what the problem means now and how to approach it.  That's pretty simple!

Comment: You are welcome! It's really simple...and don't forget to accept if you like the answer :)